# Haskell Stack Generating Duplicate Dependency?

Tags: haskell, ghc, haskell-stack

So I am in the process of updating my Haskell project from LTS 9.21 (GHC 8.0.2) to LTS 11.12 (GHC 8.2.2) and one of my existing projects  no longer compiles properly (OS: archlinux). Specifically the test binary for a library fails to compile (the library under testing compiles fine). The test binary seems to find two instances of a data type declaration which makes me think that maybe the library under testing is being duplicated? I receive the following error message:

```
• Couldn't match type ‘MyLib-0.2.1.0:MyLib.Foo.BarType’
                 with ‘BarType’
  NB: ‘BarType’
        is defined in ‘MyLib.Foo’ in package ‘MyLib-0.2.1.0’
      ‘MyLib-0.2.1.0:MybLib.Foo.BarType’
        is defined in ‘MyLib.Foo’ in package ‘MyLib-0.2.1.0’
  Expected type: IO (V.Vector BarType)
    Actual type: IO
                   (V.Vector MyLib-0.2.1.0:MyLib.Foo.BarType)
```

Possibly further supporting my theory of a duplicate dependency is the fact that underneath the .stack-work directory there exists two copies of 'MyLib' with different hash suffixes

```
$ ls .stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux-tinfo6/Cabal-2.0.1.0/build
autogen     libHSMyLib-0.2.1.0-GDttEQSehxfEGK2MpHGnkk.a            
libHSMyLib-0.2.1.0-KMd8aF0sABi30EkTXjcRNo-ghc8.2.2.so
MyLib-tests  libHSMyLib-0.2.1.0-GDttEQSfhxfEFK2MwHGnkk-ghc8.2.2.so
MyLib       libHSMyLib-0.2.1.0-KMg8aF0jABi10EkJXjcRNo.a
```

Any suggestions would be welcome.

Comment: I think anyone trying to answer the question might want to know how to reproduce the issue.
Have you tried upgrading projects from lower to higher LTS releases before with similar unsuccessful results?

Comment: Did you try `stack clean --full` and then `stack build --test` again?

Comment: @Shersh yes I have done both multiple times.

Comment: @KartikSabharwal  I have tried upgrading before to a previous LTS version (I think it was 8.1...) which led me to discovering a bug in GHC. Since then I have not attempted it again since I wanted to give GHC and libs more time to mature. I am now making another attempt. I guess since the issue is not obvious I will start removing things and then adding back.

Comment: Also not sure if this is relevant, but it seems that stack rebuilds the entire project even if I only change a test file. I don't recalls this being the previous behavior. It also seems to build the lib twice. It builds a non-test version and a test version but outputs the object files to the same place which seems weird to me. This really makes build times excessive...

Comment: A complete guess is that you have overlapping source directories. We'd need to see the contents of your `.cabal` file and/or `package.yaml` file to know for sure though.

Comment: @MichaelSnoyman I found the issue and its a regression, have filed bug: https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/issues/4081